# Paypay get transaction detail API does not work

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I used to call API https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to get the transaction detail.

But today, the api starts to return 400 bad request: Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

The body: {"cmd": "_notify-synch", "tx": transaction_id, "at": identity_token} worked well in the past and just return 400 bad request today.

Comment: Posting to `ipnpb` is for verifying a received IPN message. It does not itself provide transaction details, the IPN message you received did that. IPN is very old and should not be used in any current/new integrations, REST API Captures contain transaction details already.

Comment: @PrestonPHX thank for your comment. But I integrated Paypal to my system for 4 years and the API worked well. It just started to return 400 today. Did Paypal do something? I expected they put their change to a new version of the API, not the current version that can break old integration.

Comment: not enough information to comment on that situation